# Storing PHP OPP classes

Tags: php, namespaces, directory-structure

I have a site which uses the library file `lib.client.php` which is stored in the `php` folder in my standard website root and contains a series of classes I have built.

The library file contains about 5 or so classes, should I leave this file as one or break up the classes into their own files and include them all individually? Are there any best practice naming conventions I should use for these file(s)?

(As you can see at the moment I'm using lib. and I also use inc. - only because I have seen it done a few times before).

UPDATE:

I am remodelling my structure to comply with the PSR-0 Standard. I now have:

- CCall (Vendor)

  - Core

    - Connection

      - Gateway.php
      - GatewayDSN.php
      - GatewayException.php
  - Components

    - Environment.php
    - EnvironmentRequest.php
    - Centre.php
    - Access

      - User.php
      - UserSession.php
    - RenderException.php

I want to create a `new Environment()` in index.php, and its `__construct` method calls `Gateway::checkInstance()`.

1. How would I manage namespace use in this model? What would have its own namespace and where would I define this?
2. How would I use an autoload with these namespace definitions (and where?)
3. Is there an equivalent standard for method and property naming?

I am using this https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634/download#

Answer (score 0):

Break classes into their own files and follow the PSR-0 standard as a best practice.
http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/

Comment: I have updated my question with some changes I've made following the PSR-0 standard, are you able to answer the question on namespace with PSR-0?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a PSR-0 autoload:

add this in Environment.php

```
namespace Components;
```

and add a reference to Gateway

```
use Core\Connection\Gateway;
```

of course you need this line inside Gateway.php

```
namespace Core\Connection;
```

Then:

```
new Components\Environment();
```

Comment: And would the loader take a similar input? `$classLoader = new SplClassLoader('CCall\Components\Environment', './lib/CCall/Components');` for environment etc?

Comment: yes, first you need to register "the namespace". ```require_once("SplClassLoader.php");
$loader = new SplClassLoader('CCall\', './lib/CCall'');
$loader->register(); new Components\Environment();```

Comment: I get a syntax error because of the `\'` how can I get around that?

Comment: maybe  ```new SplClassLoader('CCall', '/lib/CCall'')```. sorry but i can't test the code.

Comment: So what does input does the class want? Is it the route to the folder the class file is contained in and the parent namespace? Aka to load environment file `new SplClassLoader('CCall\Component', '/lib/CCall/Component'')`